# How to fix all loading urls from the website using HtmlUnit?

Tags: javascript, java, google-analytics, htmlunit

Some urls are missing while getting request from `WebClient` using `HtmlUnit`.

List of Issues:

1. Not Loading urls like facebook.com with type JSON, Google Analytics urls with type JavaScript, gif and XHR.
2. For example in Google Analytics out of 5 fired 4 urls. 1 urls is not firing. Please check our code and let us know how to fire all urls at a time in `conversion.async.js`

Here is my code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);
webClient.getCookieManager().clearCookies();
webClient.getCache().clear();
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(120000);
// to wait for AJAX
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000);

webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getOptions().setDoNotTrackEnabled(false);

new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {
  int conversionUrlCount = 0;

  @Override
  public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(request.getUrl());
    WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
    if (response.getStatusCode() < 400) {
      resourceUrls.add(request.getUrl());
    }
    return response;
  }
};

String url = "abc.com",
  HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

// to forcibly load the link
HtmlLink link = page.getFirstByXPath("//link");
link.getWebResponse(true);

// to forcibly load the image
try {
  HtmlImage image = page.getFirstByXPath("//img");
  image.getImageReader();
} catch (IOException e) {
  //don't need to crash at this point,
  //just let the user know that a wrong file has been passed.
}
```

Comment: Two hints, do not use the NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController and as posted many times webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000); is not an option, call this after getPage(). And please provide more details like a url and a detailed description what you expect and what you got. If you are really sure the behavior is different from real browsers, please open a HtmlUnit issue.

Comment: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/983027267/?random=1532424560241&cv=9&fst=1532424560241&num=1&guid=ON&resp=GooglemKTybQhCsO&u_h=1080&u_w=1920&u_ah=1056&u_aw=1877&u_cd=24&u_his=2&u_tz=330&u_java=false&u_nplug=3&u_nmime=4&sendb=1&frm=0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.crowndodgechryslerjeep.com%2F&tiba=Crown%20Dodge%20Chrysler%20Jeep%20RAM%20%7C%20In%20Ventura%2C%20CA&async=1&rfmt=3&fmt=4

Real Browsers doing this request, but not in HtmlUnit.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=1602845983312973&ev=PageView&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.crowndodgechryslerjeep.com%2F&rl=&if=false&ts=1532424558578&sw=1920&sh=1080&v=2.8.23&r=stable&ec=0&o=28&it=1532424557217    and also this request, but not in HtmlUnit